# Name for a tax that captures all goods and services produced?

Tags: gdp, taxation

Is there a name for a consumption tax that basically captures the GDP (all goods and services produced in the nation)?

Answer (score 2):

Value-Added Taxes (VAT) are supposed to capture most goods and services produced in the private sector, but there can be exceptions within a country’s laws.

Even if the exceptions were eliminated, there are some non-market components to GDP that would be missed (e.g. imputed values, like the “rental value of owner-occupied housing”). (You need to go into each country’s GDP definition to find the list of imputations.)

Comment: Can you clarify the "non-market" components of GDP that would be missed?

Comment: Imputed values, like the value of free chequing accounts. Imputations vary from country to country, so you need to go to the national statistical agency for details.